# 503 error on main-website in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pool, asp.net-4.5

We have multiple websites running on our IIS7.5
Basically they are all using the same physical path, but based on the host name the content will be different.

Recently I upgraded the site from asp.net 3.5 to asp.net 4.5
So I am using a V4.0 integrated application pool now instead of the V2.0 Classic

When I am using the same applicationpool for all the sites all sites issue a 503 error.

When I am using a the old asp.net 3.5 version for the 'main site' with the V2.0 classic appliation pool,and use the new asp.net 4.5 release for the other sites, they run fine with the V4.0 applicationpool and the mainsite runs fine as well.

What I notice is that I have to leave hostname blank in the main site, if I fill it with the actual domainname I get a 503.

Does anybody have a clue what causes this issue?

Comment: That's odd. 503 happened when the application pool stop working. Did your application pool stop in IIS?

Comment: No it did not. It seems to have to do with bindings somehow. I found a way to have all domain names running now,  I use a default blank website with empty binding. It is not ideal